# Binary Search Tree String Insertion/Delete/Print

Tags: java, math, binary-search-tree

I want to insert, delete and print strings in this `BST` using a public method, as opposed to a `boolean` or `void` - so I have to return.

In my insert method I am trying to check for `null`, and left and right sides of the tree. In the case that comparison between the label and the string is `< 0` I set left to be the current node's value. And the same for the right side.

My question, what do I return at the end of this method? I am confused on this part, do I return myself in this case?

```
return false;
```

Comment: Will the downvoter please comment?

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, but posting code full of compilation problems and asking vague questions: that would be enough reasons.

Comment: Thats the only reason im posting it on stackoverflow, and pretty sure what stackoverflow is meant for.

Comment: @laune can you check the updated part now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take a look at a robust implementation of BST, here's one:

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html

Also, if you'd like to actually understand what and why is going on there, I suggest looking/reading courses there as well.

Edit:

Well, first of all, let's address a few issues here.

1. Looking at your class, you are making a claim that every `Node` is a `Tree`. Now, that might make sense, but using a `Tree` as a wrapper around a set of linked `Nodes` should be a much easier approach.
2. Speaking in so-to-say layman terms, you can do BST operation in 2 ways, recursively and iteratively. I'm going to give you an example of each.

Iterative version:

```
private void addIterative(T item) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(item);
        return;
    }

    Node parent = null;
    Node node = root;

    int cmp = 0;
    while (node != null) {
        cmp = item.compareTo(node.item);

        if (cmp == 0) {
            return;
        } else if (cmp < 0) {
            parent = node;
            node = node.left;
        } else {
            parent = node;
            node = node.right;
        }
    }

    Node child = new Node(item);

    if (cmp < 0) {
        parent.left = child;
    } else if (cmp > 0) {
        parent.right = child;
    }
}
```

Recursive version:

```
private Node add(Node node, T item) {
    if (node == null) {
        return new Node(item);
    }

    int cmp = item.compareTo(node.item);

    if (cmp == 0) {
        // it already exists
    } else if (cmp < 0) {
        node.left = add(node.left, item);
    } else {
        node.right = add(node.right, item);
    }

    return node;
}
```

In iterative version you are using a loop to move through the tree and once you find a place to add a node, you just create and link it.

On the other hand, the recursive version is, so to say, self building. On each insert, you are refreshing the links to that path, down the tree.

So, iterative - moving through tree in a while loop; recursive - moving through tree via recursive calls.

Your example leads me to believe you are meant to use iterative version of adding new elements. In that case, you are (I believe) simply required to return instance of `Tree` for method chaining, so you could do something like this:

```
node.insert("1").insert("2");
```

I would still suggest you revise the way you look at `Node`s and `Tree`s, but if that's not possible, then I guess you'll need to work your way around it somehow.

Comment: Thanks, been using this essentially. Note the updated question

Comment: Elem is a String, while the example I've given you is parametrized with T, which means you can look at T as String

Comment: But you also include a secondary node variable Node node can i use Node from above in the code?

Comment: Your BST implementation leads me to a conclusion that it's meant for you to add the element in an iterative way and then return the instance of the `Tree` for method chaining. So, if that's what it takes, then at the end you should return `this`.

Comment: Why do you check for null here     if (cmp == 0) {

Comment: That isn't a production code, I was just writing it while I was answering your question. If my BST was implementing a `Map<K, V>` interface (so, an ordered map), then in that part of the code, you could actually update the value in a node.